# Mongoose.populate() not showing any change in DB

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have been trying to populate from a user table and have been unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated.

I am checking a variable `isProvider`

```
if(true) 
   then the data is saved in a provider table 
else 
    in a customer table.
```

I want the user table to be an Auth table, so I want to populate a field called "userId" in these models. The id is being saved. When i print the results of populate, It shows a populated json but when i see it in the database it shows only the Id. I want to access the details of user table through the photographer table. How do i achieve this ?

---

User model

```
/* 
 * Title: User model
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
//Data model
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    token: String,
    mobile: String,
    type: String,
    createdOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    lastModifiedOn: {type: Date},
    deleted: {type: Number, default: 0},
    isPhotographer: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    verified: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});


UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;
    if(this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
            if(err) {
                return next(err);
            }
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
                if ( err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                user.password = hash;
                next();
            });
        });
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (passw, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(passw, this.password, function( err, isMatch) {
        if(err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

user = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = user;
```

Provider model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = require('./User');

//Data model
var providerSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    profilePicture: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'GFS'
    },
    email: String,
    phone: Number,
    address: String,
    dob: Date,
    createdOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    lastModifiedOn: {type: Date},
    deleted: {type: Number, default: 0},

});

providerSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.lastModifiedOn = new Date;
    next();
});

provider= mongoose.model('provider', providerSchema);
module.exports = provider;
```

Customer model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = require('./User');
//Data model
var customerSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
    },
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String, 
    createdOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    lastModifiedOn: {type: Date},
    deleted: {type: Number, default: 0},

});

customerSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.lastModifiedOn = new Date;
    next();
});

customer = mongoose.model('Customer', customerSchema);
module.exports = customer;
```

Controller

```
if(user.isProvider) {
                        var provider= new providermodel({
                            userId: user._id,
                            firstName: req.body.firstName,
                             lastName: req.body.lastName
                        });
                        provider.save(function(err, docs) {
                            if(!err) {

                                pprovidermodel.findOne({_id: provider._id}).populate('userId').exec(function(err, docs) {
                                    if(err) {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                    console.log(docs); ----> **Here populate works, but no changes in the database**
                                    console.log("SO " + docs.userId.email);
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        })
                    }else {
                        var customer = new customermodel({
                            userId: user.id,
                            firstName: req.body.firstName,
                            lastName: req.body.lastName
                        });
                        customer.save(function(err) {
                            if(!err) {
                                customermodel.findOne({}).populate('userId').exec(function(err, docs)
                                {
                                    console.log(err);
                                    console.log(docs);
                                })
                            }
                        })
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's right. Populate don't change values in database only retrieve values when code is running.